# jQuery unbind, then bind again

Tags: jquery, bind, unbind

i've my function (i need to unbind later):

```
$("#closebtn").click(function(){
    $.address.value('/x');
});
```

I unbind it after an event:

```
$("#closebtn").unbind("click");
```

Now I want to associate my "click" function again to my #closebtn, how can i do ?
thank you
d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign your function to a variable

```
var closebtn = function() {
    $.address.value('/x');
};
```

Then you can bind with the variable

```
$("#closebtn").click(closebtn);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is actually a button, could you just disable it, rather than unbind/re-bind. Or, add an if statement so the function returns false when you don't want it to 'fire' - I think that would be more efficient than bind/un-bind/rebind, which is fairly expensive.

Something like this, maybe?

```
$("#closebtn").click(
    function() {
        if (inEvent) {
            return false
        }
        $.address.value('/x')
    })

$('someOtherElement').click(
    function() {
        inEvent = 1
        // ...
        // do the processing where you don't
        // want the function to fire
        .. ...
        inEvent = 0
    })
```